# Jenkins - Get build number and GIT hash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline as below
JobA -> JobB -> JobC -> JobD

I want to get the build number of first job in the pipeline(i.e jobA) and the commit ID which triggered jobA.

I want to get this information in jobD

Any idea?

Comment: 1) pass as parameters to downstream jobs 2) write to file/read from file

Comment: Just also wanted to suggest the second: passing the data through all subjobs seems a bit stupid so write them to one or more files and then read them out from there in JobD. You would search for the environment variables `BUILD_NUMBER` and `GIT_COMMIT` (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)